# multiple markers not showing up in gmaps

Tags: c#, gmap.net

so I have been having issues with `gmaps` and c#
I am trying to add multiple markers and I can only get one to show up

I am extremely new to C# so forgive me if I am missing some simple, but I have been working on this for a week.  I am using vb15

```
gMap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingHybridMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
gMap.SetPositionByKeywords("Paris, France");
gMap.ShowCenter = false;

GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay markers = new 
GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay("markers");
GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
    new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(48.8617774, 2.349272),
    GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);

GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker1 = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
    new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(48.8417774, 2.449272),
    GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);

markers.Markers.Add(marker);
markers.Markers.Add(marker1);
gMap.Overlays.Add(markers);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple makers on Gmap in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325205/how-to-add-multiple-makers-on-gmap-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Your 2. point is way off:
[googlemaps](https://www.google.de/maps/dir/48.8417774,+2.449272/48.8617774,2.349272/@48.8477838,2.3806893,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!4m5!1m3!2m2!1d2.449272!2d48.8417774!1m0) - sure you see it?

Comment: Are you sure the code above is the one you're using? I cannot see anything obviously wrong in there.

Comment: it works.  thank you rdoubleui   i dont know why it didn't before, maybe i did not initialize the map correctly?

Comment: Patrick Artner  I think you are correct i decreased my zoom Thank you